# append strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some application that adds elements to `contentEditable div`.
Something like this:

```
<div id="div" contentEditable="true"></div>
<button id='appendBtn'>append</button>

<style>
    .bracket {
      color: blue;
    }

    .template-content {
      color: green;
    }

    #div {
      border: solid 1px gray;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function appendContent() {
      var content = "<span class='template-block'>" +
        "<span class='bracket'>{</span>" +
        "<span class='template-content'>param</span>" +
        "<span class='bracket'>}</span>" +
        "</span>";

        $("#div").append(content);
    }

    document.getElementById ("appendBtn").addEventListener ("click", appendContent, false);
</script>
```

I wrote a working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo32jjay/).

The problem is that when I click `append` and continue typing after added element all next text comes green. It happens because all next text pasts into last `span` tag (of class `bracket` with green color)...

```
<span class="bracket">}some text</span>
```

The solution is adding a `&nbsp;` after last closing `span` tag. Like this:

```
var content = "<span class='template-block'>" +
        "<span class='bracket'>{</span>" +
        "<span class='template-content'>param</span>" +
        "<span class='bracket'>}</span>" +
        "</span>&nbsp;";
```

But it brings a lot of unwanted staff I have to do with the text after. How can I solve this?

Comment: tried the demo, pressed 3 times the append button and then i write and it comes out blue :S

Comment: I'm testing your fiddle and it is working properly. What browser did you use?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what exactly you were looking for is space after appending each content?

Comment: nvm, there is a typo, he/she meant "blue" instead of "green". If you keep typing the font keeps blue instead of defaulting to black and you still write inside the last span tag.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca Fiddle demonstrates the problem. click append inspect the element and start typing to the end of the appended text and you see the new text ends up inside the span. OP wants that new text to be outside the span.

Comment: what do u mean by unwanted staff ?

Comment: even `&nbsp;` is not a solution as all a user has to do is delete the last whitespace to end up again in the last `<span>` - The problem is that the markup is ignored as such and what ever character you are typing behind, that is where the text ends up. You might need a possible script solution to trigger on keydown or up (haven't tested it) to take control over the text to ensure it sticks within the specified template.

Comment: All of you undertood me right, sorry, translating problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats a default behaviour of content editable setting the pointer behind the last character inside. In Your case the pointer is set

```
<span class='bracket'>}--> pointer <--</span>
```

You could try a workaround with `&#8203;` entity (zero width space)
if you dont want the `&nbsp;`

Comment: Thanks. All I have to do is `$.trim($("#div")).text().replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, ''));` to remove that symbols and send data to my php script